# using stat_summary_hex to show most frequent value with discrete color scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I have a data frame with 10k rows and 3 columns: xpos, ypos and cluster (cluster is a number from 0 to 9) here: http://pastebin.com/NyQw29tb

I would like to show a hex plot with each hexagon colored according to the most-frequent cluster within that hexagon.

So far I've got:

```
 library(ggplot2)
 library(hexbin)
 ggplot(clusters, aes(x=xpos, y=ypos, z=cluster)) + stat_summary_hex(fun.x=mode)
```

Which I think is giving me what I want (i.e. is filling in every hexagon with a color from 0 to 9), but the color scale appears continuous, and I can't figure out how to make it use a discrete one.

[image: output]

For extra context, here's the underlying, messier view of the data, which I'm trying to smooth out by using hexagons:

```
 qplot(data=clusters, xpos, ypos, color=factor(cluster))
```

[image: output2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't knw what your `stat_summary_hex(fun.x=mode)` is doing, but I'm pretty sure it's not what you think (`mode` gives the storage mode of an object, not the statistical mode, and `fun.x` doesn't match any formal argument of `stat_summary_hex`). Try this. It tabulates the observations in each bin, and pulls out the label of the maximum count.

```
ggplot(clusters, aes(x=xpos, y=ypos, z=cluster)) + stat_summary_hex(fun = function(x) {
    tab <- table(x)
    names(tab)[which.max(tab)]
})
```

[image: Hexbinned clusters]

Comment: Thanks for the sanity-check on what I'd done, and your answer is exactly what I wanted, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are two problems here. First, `mode` is not the function you want (check the help--it's to "Get or set the type or storage mode of an object"). Second, the parameter if  `fun=` rather than `fun.x=` for `stat_summary_hex`.

There's a nice discussion of mode functions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/standard-library-function-in-r-for-finding-the-mode). The recommended function is:

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
```

Finally, you want to make sure that the fill for the hexagons is treated as a discrete value. You can modify the `fun` function so that the return value is a character (as in the code below).

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(hexbin)
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
clusters=data.frame(xpos=rnorm(1000),ypos=rnorm(1000),cluster=rep(1:9,length.out=100))
ggplot(clusters, aes(x=xpos, y=ypos, z=cluster)) +
  stat_summary_hex(fun=function(x){as.character(Mode(x))})
```

I hope this helps.